# How to print from React Web App without using middle app installed on device

Tags: javascript, android, printing, progressive-web-apps

We are developing a PWA cross platform web app using Reactjs and we need to print directly through that.

As far as we have considered, a solution to handle printing on each platform like Android, is to write a native app and send the print request to it and do printing through that middle App.

I wonder is there any better solution to allow us to do the print from within the PWA app without any need to have a middle native app?

I searched a lot and there is similar questions with no answers.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `window.print()` is all we have ... ‍♂️

Comment: @JonasWilms, how we can prevent the dialog box to show?